# 'Tempted to do' or 'tempted of doing'

Tags: phrase-usage, infinitive-vs-gerund

I know that following expression is valid:

> I was tempted **to do** it.

For the context purpose, is the expression below valid as well?

> I was tempted **of doing** it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may have ***the temptation of* doing something**, but we are usually ***tempted to* do** something.

Answer (score 3):

You will find the collocation **tempted of** in texts from the 17th, 18th, and 19th centuries in linguistically (hyper-) conservative religious texts which are formulaic in their use of language. But in contemporary  English, **tempted by (something)** and **tempted to do (something)** are standard.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's grammatically valid, but no fluent speaker says that.

Yes it works with other words. "I was thinking of doing that" is very common, for example.

Comment: I don’t understand how “tempted of”  could be construed as grammatical.

Comment: I was using 'thinking of...' as a reference as well, but 'tempted of...' sounded a bit off, so I wanted to confirm if such phrase even valid.

Comment: @ColleenV Maybe it's not valid, but I can't think of rule it violates, and one can substitute other words into the same pattern and they're valid. Like, "I was thinking of doing ...", "I was dreaming of doing ...", etc.

Comment: Well I guess my point was that "I was tempted of" is not even close to the same thing as "I was thinking of". I could say "I was trampling of", but it's not right because "I was thinking of" is OK. I can't say it's *not* grammatical because I'm pretty sure it's one of those "some words just take certain prepositions" things, and TRomano has found a vintage usage that is grammatical.